# What Does "VGA 90" Mean?

Tags: terminology

I've seen the term **VGA 90** in several eBay auctions, usually in ones that are new or factory sealed.

I tried Googling it but found nothing.

What does *VGA 90* mean?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is the VGA grade assigned to that item. You were probably looking at an item related to video games. This is a grade assigned by "[Video Game Authority](http://www.vggrader.com/)".

The VGA Gold level consists of the grades 100, 95+, 95, 90+, 90, and 85+. A very small percentage of items submitted to VGA receive a Gold level grade. An items flaws must be very minor, subtle, and can often be difficult to identify with the naked eye. A collector who is extremely condition sensitive should be satisfied with the condition of a Gold level item in the vast majority of instances.

You can find more details on the following website: http://www.vggrader.com/faq.aspx

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah, so that's what it is. Thanks! (And I thought I had OCD. Sheesh, I would never pay that much for "perfect" condition; good is good enough for me if it is cheap. I would rather play and enjoy the game than just have it be perfect in a box, out-of-mind forever.)

Comment: Well neither would I..unless I guess I was swimming in cash (like Scrooge)..nope not even then either.

Answer (score 2):

A quick search shows this box art for one of those games:

[image: Video Game Authority 90+ written on Zelda box]

It appears to have been rated 90+ by a group named Video Game Authority.